# GIT Merge selected folder to another branch

Tags: git, merge

Moderators: Please help before giving -1, if you aren't sure of the answers.

I have the following structure,

> **Master**:
>
> > Folder 1
> >
> > > file1.txt
> >
> > Folder 2:
> >
> > > file1.txt
> > >
> > > file2.txt
> > >
> > > fileN.txt
>
> **Private**:
>
> > Folder 1
> >
> > > file1.txt
> >
> > Folder 2:
> >
> > > file1.txt
> > >
> > > file2.txt
> > >
> > > fileN.txt

I want to merge only all files under folder 2.

I see some other posts but I think they say about ignoring all in one branch and getting another branch. But I want to merge.

What GIT commands?

Can I use something like this?

git merge path to folder.. ?

Comment: Git doesn't merge by folder—Git doesn't care about folders, nor store folders. Git only stores *files*, inside commits. Git merges *commits*. You can, if you like, manually merge individual files, one at a time, using `git merge-file`.

Comment: That will take forever. Wondering if there was a easy way out of this pain.